# Use Anaconda's Python distribution within OSGeo4W

Tags: python, grass-gis, osgeo4w, anaconda

I want to use a Python script that executes Grass commands via `os.system()`. This of course, has to be executed from a running Grass session. However, when I use the OSGeo4W Grass, it does not find all imported packages as it falls back to its own/default Python distribution. How can I enforce OSGeo4W to use the Anaconda Python distribution?

I found a solution on the internet that makes the OSGeo4W distribution available systemwide, but not the other way around. How is it possible to do that?

Comment: What packages are missing? You can always fall back to installing the required packages into the OSGeo4W Python install.

Comment: Pandas, for example. When I try to get pip for the osgeo4w python (as described [here](https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/wiki/ExternalPythonPackages)), it tells me I don't have the write permission to a directory somewhere under QGIS/apps/Python27, even though I am admin.